# Number of solutions of $x+y+z=10$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> The number of different solutions $(x,y,z)$ of the equation $x+y+z=10$ where each of $x, y$ and $z$ is a positive integer is $36$.

How to derive this answer?

I know that $x, y$ and $z$  have to be $1\leq x,y,z\leq8$ and $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z.$ [This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14469833#14469833) said me $8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1=36.$

But I can't understand the process of counting the solutions.

Comment: For greater generality, please see the Wikipedia article on Stars and Bars. There you will see why the number is $\binom{10-1}{3-1}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, THANK YOU SO MUCH, SIR!

Comment: You are welcome. The idea of making a list, and counting the number of solutions with $x=9$, the number of solutions with $x=8$, and so on, and adding up, works nicely for $x+y+z=n$. However, that sort of approach is not really feasible for $a+b+c+d+e+f=200$. But Stars and Bars gives immediate answer $\binom{200-1}{6-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of picturing this (illustrating what **Robert Isreal** describes) is to consider the tilted plane $ \ x + y + z = 10 \ . $  In the graph below, the lines of intersection with the coordinate planes are marked in red.

[image]

The number of positive integer solutions to the equation is the number of integer lattice points that lie on that plane and *within* the triangle indicated (since we are not to include zeroes in the sums).  On the level $ \ z = 1 \ , $ there would then be eight such lattice points, seven on level $ \ z = 2 \ , $ and so on down to one on level $ \ z = 8 \ . $  This gives the number of permitted solutions as the *eighth* "triangular number", given as

$$ \left( \begin{array}{c} 8 + 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) \ = \ \frac{9!}{2! \ 7!} \ = \ 36 \ \ .$$

One could generalize this to say that the number of positive integer solutions to $ \ x + y + z \ = \ N \ $ (with integer $ \ N \ge 3 \ $ ) is the $ \ (N-2) th \ $ triangular number, $ \left( \begin{array}{c} N - 1 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) \ . $

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer!

Comment: This is connected to the material discussed in the link  **André Nicolas** gives in his comment above (which I saw only after I'd already posted).  That "partitioning" argument is related then to the extension into higher dimensions: the number of positive integer solutions to $ \ x + y + z + w = N \ $ (for integer $ \ N \ge 4 \ $ ) is the $ \ (N-3) th \ $ "tetrahedral number", $ \left( \begin{array}{c} N - 1 \\ 3 \end{array} \right) \ , $ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: $x = 1$, $z = 9 - y$, $1 \le y \le 8$.  That's the $8$.

Case 2: $x = 2$, $z = 8 - y$, $1 \le y \le 7$.  That's the $7$.

etc,

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = k + 1$, $y = m + 1$, and $z = n + 1$. Then you solve the equation: $k + m + n = 7$, and count the number of non-negative integers solution to this equation. It is a well known answer that it is: $\binom 9 2 = 36$.